# Are homological knot invariants of finite type?

Tags: knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology, categorification

It is well known that, after a change of variables, the quantum knot invariants (Jones, HOMFLY, Kauffman, etc.) can be written as power series whose coefficients are finite type (i.e., Vassiliev) invariants.  But what about their categorifications?

Specifically, do the generating polynomials of dimensions of the Heegard-Floer, Khovanov/Khovanov-Rozansky, etc., homology theories admit a change of variable such that the coefficients of the resulting power series are finite type invariants?

Comment: This is perhaps relevant: http://arXiv.org/abs/0803.1200

Comment: @Kevin: As far as I can tell, that paper says something like "categorified Jones invariants can be recovered from categorified finite type invariants".  The question I was asking is: are the categorified Jones (and other quantum) invariants recoverable from the *non-categorified* finite type invariants.  

Comment: Vivek -- excellent question! Although I think the relationship between finite type invariants and the generating functions for Khovanov homology may be trickier than just making a change of variables and taking the Taylor series.

Comment: I suspect this is not known one way or the other.  I don't think it's out of the question that the same ridiculously easy proof that works in the decategorified case (the R-matrix is congruent to its inverse mod h) works in cases like Khovanov-Rozansky, but I would have to think through the details before being sure.

Comment: I was expecting the answer to be no, because otherwise you could show that finite type invariants distinguish the unknot by using facts about Heegaar-Floer homology.

Comment: Well, I don't think that finite type invariants detecting the unknot would be surprising, though that is a good argument that someone probably would have done it if it was easy.

Comment: I guess I need some disambiguation.  What does the inquisitor mean by the "generating polynomials" of knot homology theories. Is this just the Poincare polynomial, with a variable for each grading?

Comment: @ Charlie: Yes.

Comment: I would echo ilya's answer/remark to the question as stated. However, as khovanov homology satisfies a skein long exact sequence, maybe there is a notion of finite type homological invariant, for which the statement could be true.

Answer (score 4):

If the answer were "yes" by just a change of variable, I think that would imply that the generating polynomials satisfy some kind of skein relation.  That's surely false.

Comment: Oops, I meant to just make a comment.